# Capture location of span and set style for previous upon click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, pseudo-class

I am trying to implement a star rating system and have the following code:

```
<div class="rating" style="font-size:xx-large;text-align:center;">
  <h3>Please give this course a star rating:</h3>
  <span onclick="Stars(5)">☆</span><span onclick="Stars(4)">☆</span><span onclick="Stars(3)">☆</span><span onclick="Stars(2)">☆</span><span onclick="Stars(1)">☆</span>
</div>
```

I also have the following CSS in regards to styling the icons upon hover:

```
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
width: 1.1em;
}

.rating > span:hover,
.rating > span:hover ~ span {
  color: transparent;
}

.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; 
   color: gold;
}
```

And my jQuery code is as follows:

```
function Stars(id) {
    if (id == 1)
        alert("YOU RATED THIS 1 STAR");
    else
        alert("YOU RATED THIS " + id + " STARS");
}
```

My problem is that I cannot find a way to set the color to gold upon click as when I hover off it then the star color is reset. I have tried to add an onlick event to get the number of each star so currently I am returning just an alert saying that you click 1 star, you clicked 2 stars etc.

I can see how the pseudo class is being used for the hover color how can I use a similar feature with the onclick? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you care using a click, where is your JS/Jquery?

Comment: I have just edited it, it isnt doing anything thus far other than an alert message I am just wondering how I can transform this in the same manner as the CSS so that it is set permanently

Comment: Have you considered radio buttons and JS replacement? It's a common option.

Comment: No havent considered this

Comment: Actually, based on a quick google you might try this: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/CGP87/light/ - Linked article - http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Comment: Hey your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2BtL2/1/ is working fine what you want else?

Comment: Your code is not even giving alert message

Comment: This is what I am using Paulie